# Air quality measurement, for ESP32 or Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, wearable-technology, esp32

I am looking for a sensor which can measure air quality (pollution, pollen, etc), plus temperature, humidity, CO2, etc.

It's for a hobby project. I would prefer to use an ESP32, can accept using a Raspberry Pi.

I have a strong preference for not soldering, but will, if I must. E.g things like Grove's Seeed system would be welcome. Or, I could breadboard it.

I am not going to specify exactly what I want to measure - if that is within the posting rules - just "lots of measurements, without having to pay an arm an a leg" (PM1, PM2.5, PM10, VOCs, Temperature, Humidity, Barometric Pressure, etc).

I hope that that is not too vague. I just want a sensor to use as the basis of a software project, and air quality seems like a good idea.

Bonus points if I can use it in a wearable.